# Saving a workbook into the parent folder of current subfolder

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that saves a workbook in the parent folder of its current location. The workbook is currently saved in an "internal copies" folder and I am trying to get the macro to save as into the parent folder. I'm stuck on how to parse the file path to not include the "internal copies" folder. I'm trying to avoid dedicating a cell to contain the file path and declaring that as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to work with file and path names is to use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`:

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Sub Example()
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        Dim parent As String
        'Get the parent directory:
        parent = .GetParentFolderName(ThisWorkbook.Path)
        Debug.Print parent
        Dim target As String
        'Combine path parts:
        target = .BuildPath(parent, ThisWorkbook.Name)
        Debug.Print target
    End With
End Sub
```

This is immensely less error prone than using string functions to build paths and filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the parent directory of wherever the workbook is saved at:

```
Function getParentFolder(ByVal strFolder)
        getParentFolder = Left(strFolder, InStrRev(strFolder, "\") - 1)
End Function
```

And here is a test:

```
Public Sub Test()

        Dim pth As String, savePth as String

        pth = ThisWorkbook.Path

        savePth = getParentFolder(pth)

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs savePth
End Sub
```

I checked with a workbook saved in `C:\Test\Internal Copies` and the function returned `C:\Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `..` refers to the parent directory (e.g. `C:\Temp\Temp1\Temp2\..\xxx.xlsx` is equivalent to `C:\Temp\Temp1\xxx.xlsx`), you could write something like this:

```
Sub SaveInParentDirectory()
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\..\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```